# NotFound net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on Chrome, SEC7127: Redirect was blocked for CORS request on IE

Tags: asp.net, web-services, google-chrome, cors, internet-explorer-11

I have been trying to host a website locally on IIS and when I do, the entire content does not load up.

Basically I have 3 projects in the VS 2013 solution:

Website - **Main Website**

AdminPanel - **Web CMS**

WebService - **The underlying web service(s)** `.asmx`

So the Website and the AdminPanel above refer to the Web Service.

```
Website is hosted on xxx.com.au
Adminpanel on adminpanel.xxx.com.au\Admin
WebService is on adminpanel.xxx.com.au\WebService
```

The above set up works absolutely fine on the production server, and I was brought in to bring this in-house and do not have much support or handover from the predecessors

I have tried couple of things in the past 5-6 days but in vain, so I hope someone could help or point out in the right direction..

I have set up my \drivers\etc\hosts file so that the loopback address points to `xxx.com.au` and `adminpanel.xxx.com.au`

Within my web.config for the **Website** project if I point to the web service on the **LIVE** server - the site loads up fine, but if I point it to the local one, it doesn't.

So I tried hosting the service in a different directory on the **LIVE** server, `adminpanel.xxx.com.au\Webs` and pointed to this - it still failed.

The code/compiled version of the project on the **LIVE** server is the same that I have with me, on which I am trying these steps.

These are some of the issues on the console (the page loads without the menus and other contents) - this is being read/fetched after making calls to the web service which returns the menu items, events and other information which is populated on the database:

**Chrome**: `http://www.abc.com.au/NotFound net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

**Firefox/Firebug**: Nothing..!

**IE 11**: `SEC7127: Redirect was blocked for CORS request`

So I followed a couple of links/tutorials and helpers on the internet, and added a couple of headers to my web.config files

```
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

and some variations to the above from this http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/ and other links

- Also checked the HTTP Redirect settings etc.
- Even if I just copy the contents of the `adminpanel.xxx.com.au\WebService` to `adminpanel.xxx.com.au\WebS`, and changing the references gives exactly the same errors

So I am not sure what I need to specifically set or doing wrong?
Have tried out numbers pointers available out there relating to these - but none of it has worked till now.

Comment: I have tried disabling security on the browsers as well

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved it myself..
One of the connection strings to the Entity framework and another datasource, had to hook it to SQL Server's port 1433!!!

The architecture on this one was something else, had to use an older version of IIS to point out the right error messages

Thanks